# How to delete rows with different values for variables

Tags: r, dataframe, row

In my dataset `num`

```
num
structure(list(x1 = c(52L, 74L, 61L, 63L, 44L), x2 = c(32L, 96L, 
83L, 35L, 95L), x3 = c(9L, 36L, 7L, 33L, 67L), x4 = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L), x5 = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("x1", 
"x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

there is variables x4(number) and x5(year).
The problem:  values of x4  variable for 2017 does not match with the values of x4 var for 2018 year.
For example, in my reproducible example we can see that variable x4 for 2017 has number 1, but there is no number 1 for 2018.
So we must delete number 1 from dataset(i.e delete row with it).
As well as, other  values of x4 that exist for 2017, but not for 2018.
How do that?

## update

Indeed 2017 year has 406 numbers, but in 2018 there are 1500 numbers in original dataset. it is needed the code where numbers of 2017 and 2018 years are identical , but after 406 to 1500 ,2018 has numbers?

## dput with 1500 number

```
structure(list(x1 = c(52L, 74L, 61L, 63L, 44L, 44L), x2 = c(32L, 
96L, 83L, 35L, 95L, 95L), x3 = c(9L, 36L, 7L, 33L, 67L, 67L), 
    x4 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1500L), x5 = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", 
"x5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

in output

```
x1  x2  x3  x4       x5
74  96  36  2       2017
61  83  7   3       2017
63  35  33  2       2018
44  95  67  3       2018
44  95  67  1500    2018
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# Get x4 values present for all years
x4.all <- Reduce(
   function(a, b) intersect(a, b),
   lapply(split(num, num$x5), function(x) x$x4))

# Select entries where x4 is an element of x4.all
subset(num, x4 %in% x4.all)
#x1 x2 x3 x4   x5
#2 74 96 36  2 2017
#3 61 83  7  3 2017
#4 63 35 33  2 2018
#5 44 95 67  3 2018
```

Explanation: We use `Reduce(function(a, b) intersect(a, b), ...)` to calculate the intersect of `id4` values across all `x5` (years) groups; we then filter entries based on those `x4.all` values that are present in all years.

Answer (score 1):

You could e.g. first retrieve those numbers that are present for every year, then index with them.

```
inds <- do.call(intersect, unname(by(num, num$x5, function(x) x$x4)))
num[num$x4 %in% inds, ]

  x1 x2 x3 x4   x5
2 74 96 36  2 2017
3 61 83  7  3 2017
4 63 35 33  2 2018
5 44 95 67  3 2018
```

Comment: that's works, but indeed 2017 year has 406 numbers, but in 2018 there are 1500 numbers in original dataset. Can you provide the code where numbers of 2017 and 2018 years are identical , but after 406 to 1500 ,2018 has numbers?

Comment: this scenario left only 406 numbers. 2017 year has 406 numbers, 2018 has 1500 numbers . I.E. I need to have all the same numbers 2017 and 2018 (1-406) and 
as well as, numbers that are only available for 2018 but they go from 407-1500.
do you understand what I'm talking about?

Comment: Yes, you could just add it as a condition e.g. via `num[num$x4 %in% inds | num$x5 == 2018, ]` if that is what you are looking for

Comment: something wrong, this string didn't help, well, could test on new dataset, where i added 1500 number in 2018, i edited post with num dataset structure(list(x1 = c(52L, 74L, 61L, 63L, 44L, 44L), x2 = c(32L, 
96L, 83L, 35L, 95L, 95L), x3 = c(9L, 36L, 7L, 33L, 67L, 67L), 
    x4 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1500L), x5 = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", 
"x5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Comment: I'm not sure what output you are looking for exactly :/ All of 2018, then my last code works. Only the ones they have in common? Then my original solution works. Anything different, please provide a sample output!

Comment: Yes you are right, i wrong copy-past your string, i am sorry. All good

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
nums %>%
   group_by(x4) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(x5)  == n_distinct(.$x5))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups: x4 [2]
#     x1    x2    x3    x4    x5
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1    74    96    36     2  2017
#2    61    83     7     3  2017
#3    63    35    33     2  2018
#4    44    95    67     3  2018
```